# Android sqLite Data retrieving [No Error Showing]

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Trying to retrieve the data from sqLite and show it in Alert Dialog Builder.
But not Showing the data at all. When I click on the View Button nothing happens.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.database;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    EditText first,last,age,classc;
    Button add,view;

    String FirstName;
    String LastName;
    String Class;
    Integer Age;

    sqLit myDB;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDB = new sqLit(this);

        Link();
        addButtonClicked();
        viewButtonClicked();





    }

    public void addButtonClicked()
    {
         add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                xmlToVar();
                Integer flag=myDB.insertValue(FirstName, LastName, Class, Age);
                if (flag==1)
                {
                    Context context=MainActivity.this;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Record Added" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Context context=MainActivity.this;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Error Occured" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void viewButtonClicked()
    {
         view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Cursor res = myDB.getData();
                if (res.getCount()==0)
                {
                    showMessage("Error" , "No Data Found");
                    return;
                }

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                while (res.moveToNext())
                {
                    buffer.append("ID : " + res.getString(0) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("FirstName : " + res.getString(1) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("LastName : " + res.getString(2) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Class : " + res.getString(3) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Age : " + res.getString(4) + "\n");
                    showMessage("Here is your Data",buffer.toString() );
                }



            }
        });
    }
    public void showMessage(String title, String message)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder Builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        Builder.setCancelable(true);
        Builder.setTitle(title);
        Builder.setMessage(message);

    }
    public void Link()
    {
        first=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFirst);
        last=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editLast);
        classc=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editClass);
        age=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAge);
        add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Add);
        view=(Button) findViewById(R.id.ViewAll);
    }

    public void xmlToVar()
    {
        FirstName = first.getText().toString();
        LastName = last.getText().toString();
        Class = classc.getText().toString();

            Age = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());




    }


}
```

sqLit.java

```
package com.example.database;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.text.Editable;

public class sqLit extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public static final String DB_NAME="student12.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="class1";

    public static final String COL_1="ROLLNO";
    public static final String COL_2="FirstName";
    public static final String COL_3="LastName";
    public static final String COL_4="Class";
    public static final String COL_5="Age";

    public sqLit(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +COL_1 + " INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+COL_2 + " TEXT,"+COL_3 + " TEXT,"+COL_4 + " TEXT,"+COL_5 + " INTEGER)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("Drop Table If Exist" + TABLE_NAME );
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public Integer insertValue(String firstName, String lastName, String Class, Integer Age)
    {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentV = new ContentValues();
        contentV.put(COL_2, firstName);
        contentV.put(COL_3, lastName);
        contentV.put(COL_4, Class);
        contentV.put(COL_5, Age);
        long isInserted = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentV);
        if (isInserted == -1){
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
        }

    public Cursor getData()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("Select * From "+TABLE_NAME, null);
        return res;
    }




}
```

LogCat

```
06-11 22:02:40.728: D/dalvikvm(1576): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
06-11 22:02:40.737: E/Trace(1576): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-11 22:02:40.817: D/gralloc_goldfish(1576): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-11 22:05:14.779: D/dalvikvm(1576): GC_CONCURRENT freed 197K, 5% free 6176K/6471K, paused 15ms+0ms, total 19ms
06-11 22:08:27.242: E/Trace(2066): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-11 22:08:27.322: D/gralloc_goldfish(2066): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-11 22:08:31.472: D/dalvikvm(2066): GC_CONCURRENT freed 225K, 5% free 6148K/6471K, paused 17ms+1ms, total 19ms
06-11 22:10:36.644: D/dalvikvm(2290): GC_CONCURRENT freed 225K, 5% free 6148K/6471K, paused 16ms+0ms, total 19ms
06-11 22:10:52.355: D/AndroidRuntime(2290): Shutting down VM
06-11 22:10:52.355: W/dalvikvm(2290): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3f1c288)
06-11 22:10:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2290): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 22:10:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2290): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
06-11 22:10:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
06-11 22:10:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
06-11 22:10:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
06-11 22:10:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at com.example.database.MainActivity.xmlToVar(MainActivity.java:115)
06-11 22:10:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at com.example.database.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:46)
06-11 22:10:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
06-11 22:10:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
06-11 22:10:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-11 22:10:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-11 22:10:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-11 22:10:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-11 22:10:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 22:10:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-11 22:10:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-11 22:10:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-11 22:10:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2290):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-11 22:12:22.676: D/dalvikvm(2455): GC_CONCURRENT freed 201K, 5% free 6172K/6471K, paused 17ms+0ms, total 19ms
06-11 22:14:01.238: D/dalvikvm(2652): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
06-11 22:14:01.248: E/Trace(2652): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-11 22:14:01.338: D/gralloc_goldfish(2652): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

The Button isn’t working at all.

Comment: in getData(), why are you using "SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();" ? You are not writing anything to DB there. Did you try setting BP in the ViewClick code ? Does the cursor get any data ?

Answer (score 0):

The below exception from xmlToVar method is the problem, you are calling this in addButtonClicked method

java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

If the value in Age field is not entered then this error will happen if you make empty check before calling

Age = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());

should solve the issue

Comment: Bro the Age = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString()); is working fine I have checked the database from file manager using SQLite manager and all enteries are done by the Add Button.. But The View Button Not Working Dont Know Why

Answer (score 0):

**Validate input before you use parseInt in xmlToVar():**

```
    String ageStr = age.getText().toString();

    if (ageStr != "")
        r.age = Integer.parseInt(ageStr);
```

You can also initialize `Integer age`, if there can be a default value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide information about the following :

i) Did you try to debug ?
ii) If yes, does the cursor get any data ?

Now a different approach to the problem :

Create class of data [makes it easier to handle, i.e store and fetch from database]

example :

Class :

```
public class NoticeInformation {
    private String  NoticeType, NoticeHeader, NoticeLink;
    private int Important, NoticeId, Read;

    public NoticeInformation(int NoticeId,
                             String NoticeType,
                             String NoticeHeader,
                             String NoticeLink,
                             int Important,
                             int Read){
        this.NoticeId = NoticeId;
        this.NoticeType = NoticeType;
        this.NoticeHeader = NoticeHeader;
        this.NoticeLink = NoticeLink;
        this.Important = Important;
        this.Read = Read;
    }

    public int getNoticeId() {
        return NoticeId;
    }

    public void setNoticeId(int noticeId) {
        NoticeId = noticeId;
    }

    public String getNoticeType() {
        return NoticeType;
    }

    public void setNoticeType(String noticeType) {
        NoticeType = noticeType;
    }

    public String getNoticeHeader() {
        return NoticeHeader;
    }

    public void setNoticeHeader(String noticeHeader) {
        NoticeHeader = noticeHeader;
    }

    public String getNoticeLink() {
        return NoticeLink;
    }

    public void setNoticeLink(String noticeLink) {
        NoticeLink = noticeLink;
    }

    public int getImportant() {
        return Important;
    }

    public void setImportant(int important) {
        Important = important;
    }

    public int getRead() {
        return Read;
    }

    public void setRead(int read) {
        Read = read;
    }
}
```

Database Read :

```
public List<NoticeInformation> getScheduleNotice(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        List<NoticeInformation> res = new ArrayList<>();
        String Query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME1 + " WHERE NoticeType = 'Schedule';";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query,  null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do
            {
                NoticeInformation obj = new NoticeInformation(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1),
                        cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getInt(5),
                        cursor.getInt(4));
                res.add(obj);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            return res;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Instead of handling cursor in the application end, just have the data in a list. It is easier to handle [in my humble opinion].

Try this approach and let me know the result.